# Video Autofocus not working on android

Tags: android, video, autofocus

I am attempting to make an app that records video and I want to implement continuous autofocus. I have placed the following in `surfaceCreated`

```
   public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

}

But that only autofocuses the view before recording begins. Once recording begins the autofocus isn't present. Should I place the parameter setting elsewhere?

Comment: You should call AutoFocus(callback_object) to try to auto focus, the callback will be called whenever there is a focused object, read here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#autoFocus(android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback)